# Image absolute on hover then back to relative

Tags: css

I'm creating a thumbnail effect where a user can hover over an image and it enlarges across the screen setting the position to absolute so nothing else shifts around, but on mouse off everything freaks out as it resizes back down.

```css
.thumb_img {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.thumb_img:hover {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="thumb_img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=990"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your html as well, it will be easier to help

Comment: thumbnails sit inside of a table Thumb | col2 | text | more text

Comment: what is your actual requirement?

Comment: @MohammedRabiullaRABI questions answeted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using CSS transforms instead:

```css
.thumb_img {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.thumb_img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="thumb_img" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-3/600/React.js_logo-512.png"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked! brilliant thanks, not sure who down voted your answer, but this worked. Will mark as answer after timer

Comment: `position: relative` and `width` & `height` in `:hover` are probably unnecessary.

Comment: @AriVictor appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.thumb_img {
      max-height: 100px;
      max-width: 100px;
      transition: 0.1s;
    }

    .thumb_img:hover {
      max-width: 600px;
      max-height: 600px;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      z-index: 9999;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><img class="thumb_img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=990"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img class="thumb_img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=990"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img class="thumb_img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=990"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```